# Performance cost of type conversion in Java ,How to choses?

Tags: java, casting

In many cases we need to convert the type of data, but there are more ways to convert between Number ​​and String.  How  to choses ?  Do they have different performance?
Example :
convert  int  to String

```
int i=5;
String s1=String.valueOf(i);
String s2=i+"";
String s3=Integer.toString(i);
etc..
```

convert  String to int

```
String sint = "9999" ;
int integer = Integer.valueOf(sint);
int integer = Integer.parseInt(sint);
int integer = Ints.tryParse(sint);

int integer = NumberUtils.createInteger(sint);
int integer = NumberUtils.toInt(sint);
int integer = NumberUtils.createInteger(sint);
etc..
```

Comment: Mandatory comment on this kind of optimization: unless you’re doing this billions of times or on very weak hardware, it’s extremely unlikely to be relevant compared to the I/O of your system. Look up ‘premature optimization’.

Comment: I am very glad that you can pay attention to my problems. I think it is important to know the difference and develop a good code habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefer the version that returns a primitive.

```
int integer = Integer.valueOf(sint); // unboxes Integer
int integer = Integer.parseInt(sint); // returns int
```

As for converting `int` to `String`, those perform the same (one calls the other, and the JIT optimizes away any difference there).

Comment: Although `i+""` creates an extra object, a `StringBuilder` and then throws it away.  It's fairly inefficient if done too often.  Your other two examples are I believe equivalent and preferred, as mentioned.